# django, template_docs project, LIBREOFFICE path, Failed to initialize LibreOfficeKit

Tags: django, libreoffice

Hello everyone I am trying to make [template_docs](https://github.com/alexmorozov/templated-docs) to work following the instructions:

> Installation is as simple as `pip install templated-docs`. Don’t forget
>   to add `templated_docs` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` Django settings. Then
>   specify the path to LibreOffice’s program directory in your settings:
>
> `TEMPLATED_DOCS_LIBREOFFICE_PATH = '/usr/share/libreoffice/program'`

However I am not sure about the path of libreoffice: `TEMPLATED_DOCS_LIBREOFFICE_PATH = '/usr/share/libreoffice/program'`

In my case the software is installed here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program`

Therefore I in my setting.py I added: `TEMPLATED_DOCS_LIBREOFFICE_PATH = 'C://Program Files (x86)//LibreOffice 5/program'` but it did not work.

The error that I get is `pylokit.lokit.LoKitInitializeError: Failed to initialize LibreOfficeKit`

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

Why two slashes instead of `C:/Program Files (x86)/LibreOffice 5/program`?

Anyway, according to https://github.com/xrmx/pylokit:

> LibreOfficeKit currently works only on Linux systems.

`pylokit` is imported on line 22 in templated-docs/templated_docs/**init**.py.

```
from pylokit import Office
```

Comment: LibreOfficeKit currently works only on Linux systems. This is the problem